# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: -H/-d/-X

Tags: php, curl, oauth, box-api, box

I'm trying to create an App user in box. I directly type in the request as given below in the command line, with a valid access token.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users \-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \-d '{"name": "Ned Stark", "is_platform_access_only": true}' \-X POST
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -H
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -d

[1/2]: name: "Ned Stark" --> <stdout>
--_curl_--name: "Ned Stark"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name

[2/2]:  "is_platform_access_only": true --> <stdout>
--_curl_-- "is_platform_access_only": true
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  "is_platform_access_only"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -X
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
```

Can you please help me with finding the mistake I'm making here? I have exactly followed the instructions given in the box website.

Comment: Are you actually using those backslashes in the command line? Try removing them first.

Comment: @DanielStenberg I did try removing the backslashes. I get the same error.

Comment: There's a mismatch/problem with the quoting for the data you pass in with `-d`